# How to set CSS hover on input

Tags: html, css

I have this `input` button:

```
<input class="btn" type="submit" id="query" name="query" value="Q" title="Query">
```

And this is the `CSS`:

```
.btn {
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

input.btn[type="submit"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

So, as you can see on `hover` I want the button to have a border. It doesn't work. I have multiple buttons this is the reason for applying the settings for a whole `class`.

http://jsfiddle.net/su39u2td/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two mistakes

1. Its `:hover` not `:hoover`
2. Your selector for input should be `input[type="submit"].btn:hover`

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
input[type="submit"].btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="submit" id="query" name="query" value="Q" title="Query">
```

Comment: "Your selector for input should be..." But y tho?

Answer (score 1):

Please change the spelling of `hoover` to `hover`

```
.btn:hover
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix this lines:

```
input.btn[type="submit"]:hover
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors here.

- The first one is you misspelled `:hover`
- The second one is your selector.

You have:

```
.btn input[type="submit"]:hover
```

This selects all hovered input fields of type submit inside a wrapper that has `btn` class.

You need:

```
input[type="submit"].btn:hover
```

Which selects all hovered input fields of type submit having the class `btn`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn
{
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.btn#query:hover
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="submit" id="query" name="query" value="Q" title="Query">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
input:hover
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```